# reference a regex group number when optional bracket present

Tags: javascript, regex

This javascript regex tries to convert
`href=/m3/whaever` to `href=http://abc.xyz.com/m3/whatever`

```
const link = 'http://abc.xyz.com';
return html.replace(/([(href=)|(src=")|(src=)])(\/m3)/g, '$1' + link + '$5');
```

is producing

`href=http://abc.xyz.com$5`

What did I get wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is holding the ``html`` variable ? and what you want to get exactly ?

Comment: @hamism an argument passed to the function where this code is.

Comment: read about character classes to well understand what it is.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte could you be more specific? which part of the regex?

Comment: In your whole regex you have only 2 groups which means you have access to only ``$1`` and ``$2`` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[...]` is used to specify character classes, not to group alternatives.

```
[(href=)|(src=")|(src=)]
```

matches a **single** character that's any of the characters inside the brackets, i.e. it's equivalent to

```
[cefhrs()="]
```

Use `()` to group alternatives.

```
return html.replace(/(href=['"]?|src=['"]?)(\/m3)/g, '$1' + link + '$2');
```

The `?` makes the quote characters optional, you don't need separate alternatives for them.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are for characters, not whole strings. Try this instead:

```js
const link = 'http://abc.xyz.com';
var html = '<a href="/m3/">test</a>';
console.log(html.replace(/(href=["']?|src=["']?)(\/m3)/g, '$1' + link + '$2'));
```